# Why python return None object?

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def isEmptyRet(self, cmdr, overIterate):
   //some code which changes the cmdr object
   if (some condition):
     //some code
   else:
     print("got to this point")
     print(cmdr)
     return cmdr
```

The console prints the following:

```
got to this point
{'ap': {'file
   //and some other parameters in JSON
  }}}
```

This function is called by the following function:

```
 def mod(self, tg):
  //some code
     cmdr = self.local_client.cmd(
            tg, func
   )
   //some code..
   cmdr = self.isEmptyRet(cmdr, False)
   print(cmdr)
```

Now, the console print: `None`

But the function `isEmptyRet` return object, which is not none (as we see in the console).

What can be the reason?

Comment: No, it only returns something if it's in the `else` block. Presumably you don't have a return statement in the `if` block.

Comment: Does it print "got to this point"?

Comment: @Don Yes, it prints..

Comment: `if:` is an invalid `if` statement. Please make sure the code you post can actually run.

Comment: @chepner I correct it, it not the issue of the question so I wrote pseudo code. Sorry for that. My code can run.

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to paraphrase your code when you don't know where the problem is. Make sure your code is something that we can run to reproduce your problem. As it is, we cannot. Many times, just the process of creating a minimal working example will show you  what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function that doesn't explicitly return a value during execution a `None` value is returned. As an example

```
def fun(x):
    if x < 10:
        # Do some stuff
        x = x + 10
        # Missing return so None is returned
    else:
        return ['test', 'some other data', x]

print(fun(1))
print(fun(11))
```

The console output would be:

```
None
['test', 'some other data', 11]
```

The reason is that when the condition `x < 10` is run there is no `return` statement that gets executed and Python will return `None` for the value of the function

Compare that to this:

```
def fun(x):
    if x < 10:
        # Do some stuff
        x = x + 10
        # This time is x < 10 we use return to return a result
        return ['test', 'some data', x * 5]
    else:
        return ['test', 'some other data', x]

print(fun(1))
print(fun(11))
```

The output would be

```
['test', 'some data', 55]
['test', 'some other data', 11]
```

Comment: Perfect! This is the answer. Not sure why this is not accepted as a solution.

Answer (score -3):

In your code, if the flow of execution come in `isEmptyRet` and in `if` statement will evaluate to true then function return None by default.